# Background-image won't show

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to have a background image in the header of my website but as of now it won't show. My file setup is as follows:

D:\ mywebsite

Image, home.css, index.html

**Image** rocks.jpg

The code I currently have is :

```
<div class="header-image" style=background-image: url("../Image/rocks.jpg")>
</div>
```

**Edit**

CSS:

```
#header .header-image {
    width: 100%;
    height: 400px;
    background-position: left center;
    background-size: 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: Did you check the browser console? May be it is not finding the image, An error must appear in red letters

Comment: Does your div have width and height?

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5846637/why-an-inline-background-image-style-doesnt-work-in-chrome-10-and-internet-ex

Comment: @varunvlalan yeah im setting the width and height

Comment: @wilsotobianco in the devtool I get an 'invalid property value'  but it's just a warning not an actual error

Comment: your `style` syntax is wrong. It's not formatted as per html basic rules. Also try use proper images directory.

Answer (score 2):

Your `style` attribute should have quotation marks around the in-line css, and the `..` in the file path will be sending you back a directory (and so must be removed), like so:

```
style =  'background-image:url("Image/rocks.jpg");'
```

EDIT: Note that you must use single quotes to surround the css or the double quotes within `url("Image/rocks.jpg")` will be interpreted as closing the quotes.

Comment: ailed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

Comment: Is the Image directory in the same place as index.html?

Answer (score 0):

if your directory is setup like

- **D:\mywebsite\**
- **D:\mywebsite\index.html**
- **D:\mywebsite\Image\**

Then this will be your answer

```
<div class="header-image" style=background-image: url("Image/rocks.jpg")>
</div>
```