# Can't set background image in flask made web-page

Tags: python, css, flask, jinja2

I'm trying to put background image inside HTML document using following code

```
<body style="background-image: url( {{url_for('static', filename='img/library2.jpg') }} )">
```

But it just doesn't work.
My console output is:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [23/Jan/2017 23:21:12] "GET /index HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [23/Jan/2017 23:21:12] "GET /static/styles.css HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [23/Jan/2017 23:21:15] "GET /static/img/favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200
```

So I don't even have get request for the img/library2.jpg.
Not sure what I'm missing

Comment: and what do you get in HTML after rendering it ?

Comment: regular white background, as if nothing about background is specified, other elements are fine.

Comment: I don't ask what you see in browser but I ask about HTML - source code - which is displayed in browser. Browser has function "show source code" so you can see what you have in `style="background-image: ..."`

Comment: BTW: [Why an inline “background-image” style doesn't work in Chrome 10 and Internet Explorer 8?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5846637/why-an-inline-background-image-style-doesnt-work-in-chrome-10-and-internet-ex)

Comment: Sorry, my bad, only <body> tag no style attribute

Comment: body even without `style="background-image:` ? then you have to use wrong file to render page.

Comment: Yes even without style="background-image: . Well, I'm rendering index.html which inherits (via Jinja2 inheritance) from base.html. The problem code is within base.html. Everything else inherits and renders just fine.

Comment: it seems you put `style` in one file but `jinja` uses different file to render page. I don't know what you have in `base` and `index` but usually `<body>` is in `base` and you should use `style` in this file.

Comment: Ok, my base was inheriting from "bootstrap/base.html", so jinja probably rendered body from that file. It works just fine without it. Since your comments lead me to the solution I would like to accept your answer if you answer it (copy the last comment or something)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you put `style` in one file but `jinja` uses different file to render page.

I don't know what you have in `base.html` and `index.html` but usually `<body>` is in `base.html` and you should use `style` in this file.