# inline style css background in react not showing

Tags: css, reactjs, react-slick

What is the problem in my code? This is a slider:

```
<Slider {...settings}>
            {slides.map(function(item){
                return (
                    <div key={item.id} className="item-slider" 
                        style={{background: `url(images/covers/${item.cover})`}}>
                        <div className="caption">
                            <h4>{item.topic}</h4>
                            <p>{item.title}</p>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                    )  
            })}
        </Slider>
```

I'm using `react-slick`, and I tested if the `item.cover` is receiving some data, and it did receive data. but when I put the data in the style it does not appear inspecting it and it does not receive any errors.

Sample: [code here](https://codesandbox.io/s/5v0308l68k)

Comment: You could try backgroundImage instead of background? If you post a jsfiddle I could help more.

Comment: @BenLorantfy i'll try posting but im using a json-server

Comment: Try opening the generated image url direct in your browser: http://localhost:3000/images/covers/cover-slug.png, check if the path is correct

Comment: @PedroFernandes tried it it's correct

Comment: try adding slash before images in url

Comment: @Developerkt did not work either! it's much easier if i got an error. but get nothing.

Comment: this link may help you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5846637/why-an-inline-background-image-style-doesnt-work-in-chrome-10-and-internet-ex?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: @Developerkt did not help either. but thanks for the effort! really appreciate it!

Comment: did you try using  `backgroundImage: `url(images/covers/${item.cover})`` instead of background and url should not be enclosed whthin quotes

Comment: did not work, you need template strings `` to access the map function inside the style

Comment: thats a typo this is what i mean '{backgroundImage: `url(images/covers/${item.cover})' }'

Comment: turn out much worst haha

Comment: can you add a jsfiddle?

Comment: @KomolafeTolulope check this codesandbox.io/s/5v0308l68k

Comment: please, check your chrome developer console network tab if images are received there

Comment: @KomolafeTolulope i'm not receiving it

Comment: @KomolafeTolulope but using img tag sure works! but then again i need it on the background for looping

Comment: I took a look at the sandbox. It doesn't seem like you have an images folder. You should have an `images` folder with a `covers` subdirectory

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issue, try **wrapping every slide into a div** like this:

```
<Slider {...settings}>
   <div>
      <div className='slider__image' style={{'backgroundImage': `url(${House})`}} />
   </div>
   <div>
      <div className='slider__image' style={{'backgroundImage': `url(${Map})`}} />
   </div>
   <div>
      <div className='slider__image' style={{'backgroundImage': `url(${NotAvailable})`}} />
   </div>
</Slider>
```

This way I got it working.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please know that answers need explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You missing to define:

`require()`

`height` image

`backgroundRepeat`

```
<Slider {...settings}>
            {slides.map(function(item){ 
               console.log(item.cover, 'check this');
                return (
                <div key={item.id} className="item-slider" style={{
                  background: 'url(' + require(`./images/covers/${item.cover}`) + ')', backgroundRepeat: 'no-repeat', height: 300 }}>
                  <div className="caption">
                    <h4>{item.topic}</h4>
                    <p>{item.title}</p>
                  </div>
                </div>
                    )  
            })}
        </Slider>
```

[image: Edit nkrjnwlkoj]

**Update**: as you mentioned in comments that the path is from the public folder use `process.env.PUBLIC_URL` to access public folder

```
  <div key={item.id} className="item-slider" style={{
                    background: 'url(' + process.env.PUBLIC_URL +`/images/covers/${item.cover}` + ')', backgroundRepeat: 'no-repeat', height: 300 }}>
```

Comment: i defined it under style.css

Comment: yeah no luck. but if i try <img> it does appear.

Comment: yes i've check the exact same path. it does appear in <img>

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/5v0308l68k here you go, i can't upload images folder says it's unauthenticated?

Comment: Module not found: Can't resolve './images/covers' this is what i receive

Comment: same result, my images folder is inside the public folder. just so you know.

Comment: Are you sure `{item.cover}` incloded the image extention, like `1.png`?

Comment: no code, unreachable code? . where do i exactly put that

Comment: Module not found: Can't resolve '../public/images/covers'

Answer (score 0):

I think I got it. Try importing the image at the top of the file, and then using the import variable as the url. I got it to work:
https://codesandbox.io/s/xvnq2q21w4

```js
import photo from "../img/reed.jpg";

const styles = {
  background: `url(${photo})`
};
```

Comment: uhh, i'm getting the filename from a table check db.json, inline with the item.id

Comment: oh yeah, sorry. I'll keep looking

Comment: I think this is the solution:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/30868078/6172657

Comment: Can you share your webpack config? I'm guessing that you can get it to work if (1) webpack properly transpiles the files, and (2) you have the correct transpiled path.

Comment: where can i find that? sorry i'm quite new to this.

Answer (score 0):

[image]Below is an example I tried to load images in the background and it worked :)

```
   Sample response. Here you can see, I have added require.

    const items = [{
        name: 'hola',
        background: require('./img-placeholder.png')
    },{
        name: 'cola',
        background: require('./img-placeholder.png')
    },{
        name: 'lola',
        background: require('./img-placeholder.png')
    }]

    const renderImages = items.map((val, key) => {
        return <div key={key} >
            <div style={{ background: `url(${placeholder})`, height: 200 }}>
            <div className="caption">
                        <h4>{val.name} -  {key}</h4>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    });
```

Note : The require() method is used to load and cache JavaScript modules. So, if you want to load a local, relative JavaScript module into a Node.js application, you can simply use the require() method.

Answer (score 0):

You have to import image at the top of your file as

```
import myimage from './images/covers/imagename';
```

Also you can use dynamic importing like :

```
 import(`${path}`)
  .then(module => this.setState({ module: module.default }))
```

Then you can use image, where cover would be import name like:

```
<Slider {...settings}>
        {slides.map(function(item){
         import(`${path}`)
         .then(module => 

            return (
                <div key={item.id} className="item-slider" 
                    style={{background: `url(images/covers/${item.cover})`}}>
                    <div className="caption">
                        <h4>{item.topic}</h4>
                        <p>{item.title}</p>

                    </div>
                </div>
                );  )
        })}
    </Slider>
```

Comment: uhh, i use map() to access the paths cause i have the filename under my db.json

Comment: Yes thats fine just import the files before using via dynamic imports and use the import name to use images or other media

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
backgroundImage: "url(" + require("../../img/img.png") + ")"
```

assuming the **img.png** is in **img** folder under **src** (webpack)

Answer (score 0):

Okay, for some reason you can't add **styling** to the element you are using to house the **return** content. So here's what you're gonna do:

```
       <Slider {...settings}>
            {slides.map((item) => {

                return(
                    <div key={item.id} className="sliderImage">
                        <div className="backImage" style={{background:`url(/images/covers/${item.cover})`}}>
                            <div className="slideCaption">
                                <h4>{item.title}</h4>
                                <h1>{item.topic}</h1>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                )
            })}
        </Slider>
```

I hope this helps you solve your problem. ;)